# Erro org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect does not support identity key generation

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Esse erro aparece quando eu vou salvar uma entidade no banco de dados. Eu configurei a classe de Entidade e o Repositório de várias maneiras, mas o erro permanece. Estou usando o Firebird 2.5.

A tabela faz o incremento automático da coluna id por Trigger.

Peço ajuda, porque não sei como resolver este problema de inserir um registro sendo que o banco que fica responsável por gerar o id.

**Log**

```
Informações:   14.09.2017 18:24:19 [http-listener-1(3)] 36108 ERROR (default) java.lang.Object - org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect does not support identity key generation
Informações:   14.09.2017 18:24:24 [http-listener-1(3)] 41355 ERROR (default) java.lang.Object - Transaction already active
```

Abaixo é a classe `Entity`:

```java
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "SMADISPO")
 public class SmadispoEntity {

     @Column(name = "ID_SMADISPO", table = "SMADISPO", nullable = false)
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer idSmadispo;

     @Column(name = "CODIGO", table = "SMADISPO")
     @Basic
     private Integer codigo;

     @Column(name = "DESCRICAO", table = "SMADISPO", length = 40)
     @Basic
     private String descricao;
 }
```

E abaixo é a classe que está sendo executada para salvar a entidade no banco de dados.

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        if (!entityManager.contains(entity)) {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
        } else {
            return entityManager.merge(entity);
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return entity;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Abaixo é a imagem da tabela no banco e a trigger que gera o ID.

[image: Estrutura da Tabela do banco de dados]

[image: Trigger que gera o ID.]

Comment: Está claramente dizendo que o Firbird não suporta geração de chave com identity. Portanto você terá que mudar o GenerationType para outro tipo (SEQUENCE, AUTO... depende).

Comment: Já mudei, mas mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Coloca o novo código e nova mensagem de erro.